# Log entire IO of a scripted process with PTY.spawn

Tags: ruby, io, pty

```
require 'pty'
require 'expect'

reader, writer, _pid = PTY.spawn('irb')

# log = StringIO.new # or maybe something else
# Attach/Tee logger to reader/writer

reader.expect(/.*> /, 1) do |line|
  puts "Line = #{line}"
  writer.puts '1+1'
end

10.times do
  reader.expect(/.*[\r\n]/, 1) { |line| puts "Line = #{line}" }
end

# puts log.string
```

Is there a way to log the entire session of the scripted process?

In this example the output should look something like:

```
irb(main):001:0> 1+1
=> 2
irb(main):002:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Open3](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html). It's already built into ruby and lets you look through all the streams in the terminal. You might want either popen3 or capture3